# How to Insert Date and Time inside the Gridview

Tags: datetime, gridview, time, record

Again, New issue. Please be guided to the image below.

[image]

Here's the output (see the image below):
[image]

Here's the code of my Gridview in results.aspx

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ID" BorderStyle="Ridge" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="3" Width="1000px" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="2">
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:boundfield DataField="Time In" HeaderText="Time In" SortExpression="Time In">
                    <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                </asp:boundfield>
                <asp:boundfield DataField="Username" HeaderText="Bar Code No." SortExpression="Username">
                </asp:boundfield>
                <asp:boundfield DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
                </asp:boundfield>
                <asp:boundfield DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName">
                </asp:boundfield>
                <asp:boundfield DataField="MiddleName" HeaderText="Middle Name" SortExpression="MiddleName">
                </asp:boundfield>
                <asp:boundfield DataField="ContactNumber" HeaderText="Contact No." SortExpression="ContactNumber">
                </asp:boundfield>
                <asp:boundfield DataField="PlateNumber" HeaderText="Plate No." SortExpression="PlateNumber">
                </asp:boundfield>
                <asp:boundfield DataField="Color" HeaderText="Color" SortExpression="Color">
                </asp:boundfield>
                <asp:boundfield DataField="Brand" HeaderText="Brand" SortExpression="Brand">
                </asp:boundfield>
                <asp:boundfield DataField="LiscensedNumber" HeaderText="Liscensed No." SortExpression="LiscensedNumber">
                </asp:boundfield>
                <asp:templatefield>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Image
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Eval("Image") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Image")) : string.Empty %>" alt="image" height="85" width="85" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:templatefield>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="#003399" />
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                No data found!
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A0A0A0" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Please help. I don't know the code regarding "Date and Time" thing.

Comment: the datafield (Time In) for time is wrong.. it cannot have spaces

Comment: I already remove the space, but no changes at all.

Comment: you need to check your collection (AccessDataSource1), if you really have a TimeIn field, if no, you need to add one and bind the value in it ..may be with date field (which i am sure you will be having)..

Comment: @RahulR. i checked it, I have the value "TimeIn" in my database. the format is Date/Time. why still not appearing

Comment: try changing the sortexpression as well, remove spaces..double check if the name in DB and datafield is same..

Comment: @RahulR. is there another codes from displaying the date and time? or it's just only creating TimeIn field in access then making the data type as Date/Time? is there a code behind?

Comment: i already solved this issue :) i convert the column in templatefield then i added this code Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd<br /> MMMM dd,  yyyy<br /> hh:mm tt") %> :) thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing space in your datafield, as by Rahul R.
 It does not matter in the Header Text but in datafield it does.

Comment: I remove the spaces but still there's no date and time showing in my gridview

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="Your_Date_Column" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
```

also make sure there are no spaces in datafield name

Comment: I already remove the spaces but the output is still the same. No date and time showing

Comment: and does it match with the name of your data source?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking here, I solved it.

I convert the column in templatefield then I added this code

```
Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd<br /> MMMM dd,  yyyy<br /> hh:mm tt") %>
```

:) thanks to all of you.

Comment: If you've solved your own question, please consider marking your answer as accepted so others know this problem alrady has a solution. Thanks